# Set Minimum Number in ComboBox

Tags: vb.net

I am using this line to generate a collection of numbers for my ComboBox.

```
Main.ComboBox.Items.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1, maxNum).Select(Function(s) s.ToString()).ToArray())
```

I was wondering how I could set the minimum for it? For example, 6-100, instead of its default 1-100.

Update:

I am using numberSetting with a Value of 0 in Project Properties Settings tab.

numberSetting is getting its actual value from:

```
My.Settings.numberSetting = CInt(ComboBox.Text)
```

Once numberSetting has its value, I use it with maxNum to set the maximum number of options in the ComboBox:

```
Dim maxNum = My.Settings.numberSetting
    Dim winners = Enumerable.Range(1, maxNum).OrderBy(Function(r) rand.Next()).Take(5).ToArray()
```

This allows me to get 100 checkboxes if I select 100 as my option from the ComboBox. What I am looking to do is the set the minimum option to 6, so that 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 are not options in the ComboBox.

SOLVED:

```
Private Sub Options_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim maxNum = My.Settings.numberSetting2
    NumberCombo.Items.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(6, maxNum - 5).Select(Function(s) s.ToString()).ToArray())
End Sub
```

Where My.Settings.numberSetting2 has a default value of 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. However, notice that the arguments are *start* and *count* (not *max*). Thus, you should adjust your `ComboBox` initialization like this:

```
Dim minNum As Integer = 6
Dim maxNum As Integer = 100
Main.ComboBox.Items.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(minNum, maxNum - minNum + 1).Select(Function(s) s.ToString()).ToArray())
```

Note that you should change `Range(1, maxNum)` to `Range(minNum, maxNum - minNum + 1)`

**Edit:**

This is how the result of the program will be

Before: there is no item in the `ComboBox`

[image]

The Code: shows the use of `Enumerable.Range`

[image]

After: shows the result in the `ComboBox` from the beginning after the `Button` Click

[image]

---

If you use it right and you have made sure to clear the previous `ComboBox` items, the `Enumerable.Range(minNum, maxNum - minNum + 1)` *should* work fine.

---

**Edit 2:**

If you still have some values after all those, then probably you have a hardcoded value in your `ComboBox`. In that case, maybe you want to check your `designer` -> Click on the `ComboBox` -> check its `Collection` property. There might be some hardcoded values there. Alternative, try to implement `ComboBox.Items.Clear()` before adding the items to make sure that everything is cleared up.

Comment: Hmm, I wasn't having any luck with that. I still had 1-100 in the dropdown and that was making my checkboxes start at 6 to 100, instead of just 6 checkboxes. Also I have maxNum set as a my.settings.numberSetting with a value of 0 to help pull back the setup on next program startup. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @RockGuitarist1 emm, pretty hard for me to imagine. Probably you could help by updating the question? Seems like it is an inference of the original issue, since the `Enumerable.Range` by itself should be able to give you the range of value you want.

Comment: Updated my question above with more detail.

Comment: @RockGuitarist1 I look at that, you still have `Dim winners = Enumerable.Range(1, maxNum)` there... see that you use `1 to maxNum` - which shouldn't be used. change that to `6 to maxNum - 6 + 1`. Anyway, you seem to get the idea of `Enumerable.Range` incorrect (I maybe wrong, but that's the impression I got). You do not get `6` items in `ComboBox` by setting it to minimum of 6, you will get 6 items *less*

Comment: I reverted back to what I started with since having (minNum, maxNum - minNum + 1) caused my range to start with 6, instead of 1. I'm just looking to get rid of 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 from the ComboBox, so that the smallest value can only be 6, therefore if 6 is selected, it will make 6 checkboxes labeled 1-6. I'm still kinda new to VB.

Comment: @RockGuitarist1 how do you put the items in the `ComboBox`? This way: `Main.ComboBox.Items.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1, maxNum).Select(Function(s) s.ToString()).ToArray())` - as shown in your question, right? If that is the way you put item in your `ComboBox`, you *really only* need to change that into `Main.ComboBox.Items.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(6, maxNum - 6 + 1).Select(Function(s) s.ToString()).ToArray())` to make 1-5 disappear from the `ComboBox` - or is there anything I miss which you do not put in the question here?

Comment: You are correct. Whenever I change it to (6, maxNum - 6 + 1) this is what I get: [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/au52by)

Comment: @RockGuitarist1 strange, I cannot reproduce your case. Maybe there is something else in the code which you have not shown? I edited my answer showing how exactly how I did it and the result I got from it.

Comment: I am just as confused. I have everything the way you have it, except I have maxNum setup to be the value that a user has previously selected 'numberSetting', which wouldn't have an effect on it, even though by default it is 0 until a user does select something from the ComboBox.

Comment: Could you include the relevant codes? Everything that has `ComboBox` in it I mean.

Comment: That is the only one with ComboBox in it. So I deleted it and reran the program, and there are still values in the ComboBox, yet the Collections is empty. So I have no idea where it is getting values from now...

Comment: In that case, maybe you want to check your `designer` -> Click on the `ComboBox` -> check its `Collection` property. There might be some hardcoded values there. Else, try to implement `ComboBox.Items.Clear()` to make sure that everything is cleared up.

Comment: Ok I think we are getting somewhere. For some reason, values were hardcoded into the Collection, so I removed them and moved the line of code to on_load and it is now working. Only issue now is, that if you select the biggest number in the ComboBox, it automatically adds 10 to the ComboBox. [example](http://prntscr.com/aug672)

Comment: @RockGuitarist1 as expected. :) ah yes... that could be a different issue. Maybe you could post a new question for that.

Comment: A spark went off in my brain and I fixed that by just creating another setting with a maxNum as 100 and then subtract it by 5. Ill post it above.

Comment: @RockGuitarist1 great!